# `pyproj` initialization error in PyCharm but not in cmd?

Tags: python, pyproj, pycharm, conda

I am currently struggling to get `pyproj` to initialize when running in PyCharm. Oddly enough, I am able to get it to work in cmd.

The version of `pyproj` I am using is 1.9.6, and the version of proj4 I am using is 5.2.0.

The following runs without error using the Python interpreter:

```
import pyproj
pyproj.Proj({'init': 'epsg:26910'})
```

However, when running from PyCharm the following error is produced:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/frankbr/.PyCharmCE2019.2/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 5, in <module>
    pyproj.Proj({'init': 'epsg:26910'})
  File "C:\Users\frankbr\.conda\envs\pyfor_env\lib\site-packages\pyproj\__init__.py", line 362, in __new__
    return _proj.Proj.__new__(self, projstring)
  File "_proj.pyx", line 129, in _proj.Proj.__cinit__
RuntimeError: b'no arguments in initialization list'
```

Due to other dependencies, and the fact that it runs in cmd (and Travis tests) without error, I am hoping to find a solution that only requires modification to PyCharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environmental variable `PROJ_LIB` needed to be set to the location of the files used by the proj library. In my case that was in the following directory:

```
'C:\\Users\\frankbr\\.conda\\envs\\pyfor_env\\Library\\share'
```

Editing the build configuration in PyCharm allows for modification of environmental variables. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708389/how-to-set-environment-variables-in-pycharm) tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

The normal way to use conda is to [activate](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/glossary.html#activate-deactivate-environment) an environment where proj is installed, which sets `PROJ_LIB` to the correct path.

However, it's not always possible to run "activate", for instance from PyCharm or Spyder IDEs. Here is my workaround that works for a few scenarios:

```
import os

# workaround if activate is not called
conda_prefix = os.environ.get('CONDA_PREFIX', '')
if conda_prefix and not os.path.isdir(os.environ.get('PROJ_LIB', '')):
    proj_lib = os.path.join(conda_prefix, 'Library', 'share', 'proj')
    if os.path.isdir(proj_lib):
        os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = proj_lib
    else:  # assume older
        proj_lib = os.path.join(conda_prefix, 'Library', 'share')
        os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = proj_lib
```